# p4 command not working p4 -Ztag -F "%depotFile%" files @= 12345

Tags: cmd, perforce

when i am trying use below p4 command i am getting an error as

**p4 -Ztag -F "%depotFile%" files @=    12345**

*Perforce client error:
        p4 -h for usage.
        Invalid option: -F.�*

But same  command working in other systems could u please help with issue

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with Python.  Also, %depotFile% is a format string, not an env var.  Also, Python 4 doesn't exist yet.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-F` option was added in the 2013.2 release (read [here](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/15148)). Based on the message I think you're using an older version which doesn't know about `-F` yet.

Please run `p4 -V` and see the version of your client (the last line of the output). If it's pre-2013.2, you'll need to upgrade.

Comment: Spot on with the version, but I feel obliged to warn that the linked KB article has a large number of inaccuracies (the entire thing on specs with `-e` is completely wrong and you could easily waste a lot of time trying to make sense of it).  My original blog article on the feature is the best doc on it as far as I know: https://www.perforce.com/blog/fun-formatting